# How do you visualize topics with multiple attributes in d3js?

Tags: javascript, visualization, d3.js

Suppose I have a list of topics with various attributes, e.g,.

```
topic1  - a,b,c,d
topic2  - b,d,z,y
topic3  - m,n,y,a,z
topic4  - u,i,v,a
```

Each topic may have a variable number of attributes.

I have seen a mxn grid.

What I really want to do is display all the data and then allow the user to choose a particular attribute.  Then display/highlight topics which have that attribute.  Once I am done with my analysis, I want to go back to viewing all topics

I also want the topics displayed clearly.

The interactive-tree in d3js examples does this.  However, I am not sure if it can be used in this case.

Comment: You'll need to give us more information. What visualisation are you thinking of? You could certainly build an interactive tree with the topics at the top level and the attributes at the lower levels but whether that's suitable depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: Here is the d3 tree for reference: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html  I want a strcutured layout like a tree.  however, my leafs have multiple parents.  Can I create a tree where the leafs have multiple parents?  Is there any alternative form I should look at?  I would be interested in any examples which represent similar data.  Note: I don't want a graph/network.  The only other visualization I have seen is a mxn grid.  However, I also want to collapse and expand selections

Comment: A tree where a node can have multiple parents is a graph. Have a look at the graph examples.

Comment: There are also solutions like [crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) The site has a good example with d3.